# How to open RDLC in Design mode

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

In my project i  have created .rdlc file in xml formate, i want to see my report but it's not showing in design view.
How can i get this?

Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 17):

From your Visual Studio 2017 top menu:

- go to **Tools** menu
- select **Extensions and Updates...**
- now, from the left panel, choose **online**
- from the top-right corner, search : **rdlc report**
- choose **Microsoft RDLC Report Designer** and click download
- when download completed, close the visual studio to let installation begin

Now, you can re-open Visual Studio again, and double-click your reports to open in designer.

---

You may also find this old solution useful: [SSRS report definition is newer than Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902037/ssrs-report-definition-is-newer-than-server)

Comment: Works for me on VS-19

Comment: In VS-2019 just go to Extensions, skip the first step.

Answer (score 6):

On the Solution Explorer pane, right click your rdlc file, select Open with, then select Report Designer. You can also set it as default in this menu, if you like

Hope that helps

Comment: There is no Report Designer option for me

Comment: There is no Report Designer for me too

Answer (score 5):

### Follow below to install the Microsoft RDLC Report Designer

1. Go to Tools menu (If using VS 2019 Extensions menu will be
   available on top)
2. Select **Extensions and Updates**.
3. Choose **Online option**
4. Search for: **rdlc report** in search window as below
5. Select **Microsoft RDLC Report Designer** and click download as
   shown below image link

when download completed.
You should close the visual studio to let installation happen.
Now, you can **re-open Visual Studio again**, and double-click your reports to open in designer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Visual Studio Version you need to install some `RDLC` extension.

Answer (score 0):

If your .RDLC is opening as XML in Visual Studio by default, then you would need to install the correct version of RDLC Designer extension for Visual Studio. You can compare which ReportViewer version you are using by looking at the tag where you are including report viewer control on the web page.

> 

For example for Version 14.0.0.0, you can download the correct extension from Visual Studio Marketplace a link provided below which matches with Report Viewer version 14.0.0.0 and Visual Studio 2017

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001

Answer (score 0):

Once you install **Microsoft RDLC Report Designer** extension as in below steps. The Report designer option will be shown on file right click properties

Answer (score 0):

On the Solution Explorer pane, right click your rdlc file, select Open with, then select Report Designer.
If the Option is not available and you have "Microsoft RDLC Report Designer" already installed on your project, go to installed section instead of online search and check if it has been disabled for some reason when you opened the rdlc in code.