# How to make report on 2016 SSRS Report Server and upload it to 2014 SSRS Report Server?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

It seems like there is not a backward compatibility option to upload the new version report to a older version server.

Comment: There is not, but you can edit the file.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902037/ssrs-report-definition-is-newer-than-server/

Answer (score 2):

this is a 2 step process.

1. On the Project Properties page, set the targetServerVersion to `SQLServer 2008 R2, 2012 or 2014`

[image]

2. Deploy from the bin folder of your project.   (if you are manually deploying/uploading).

When building the report, VS2015 will create the RDL file in the \bin directory that targets the correct version of SSRS

You can also right Click | deploy from your project if the settings above have the relevant values