# report definition is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

Previously, the web application is using VS2010 to develop SSRS report.
but when I want to upload the rdl file to server (Windows Server 2008) ..currently, I'm using VS2015 to develop the new report.
it cause the following error.

The report definition is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. This could be the result of publishing a report definition of a later version of Reporting Services, or that the report definition contains XML that is not well-formed or the XML is not valid based on the Report Definition schema. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded. (rsInvalidReportDefinition)

Other developer suggest that, change the path to target 2010 version, then will solve the problem, but that is not the way to solve it.

NOTE: The URL provided in Error is empty.

and the reporting server is Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 10.50.6000.34

then which version that i should choose for?

-SQL 2008
-SQL 2008 R2, SQL 2012, SQL 2014
-SQL 2016+ (new in VS 2015 with latest SSDT-BI)??

Comment: What version of reporting services is running on the server?

Comment: You could try changing the TargetServerVersion in the project properties to see if that helps. Not really sure it will if you are uploading RDL manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS 2014 report deploy issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188874/ssrs-2014-report-deploy-issue)

Comment: @BishNaboB version 2010
 How to go to changing the TargetServerVersion in VS2015?
I already update the details..what i missing installation in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Have a look at my answer under the duplicate and see if that helps.

Comment: @SMM it does not help at all, once i click on Build, the RDL become 2016 version still caused can't upload to the server.

Comment: The RDLs in the project folder will be 2016 no matter what you do. They will automatically upgrade every time you open them. However as long as you set you target to the appropriate SQL version the RDLs in the \bin folder will be the correct version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is 
Make back up of your .sln file
Open your VS 2010 .sln in notepad.

It should look something like this:
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00

## Visual Studio 2010  Project("{FAE04EC0-3 ......

Change the Version 11.0 to Version 10.0 and the Visual Studio 2010 to 2008

It should look something like this:
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00

## Visual Studio 2008  Project("{FAE04EC0-3 .....

From: [How to downgrade from Visual Studio 2012 project to Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507901/how-to-downgrade-from-visual-studio-2012-project-to-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 0):

Check remarks answer on this post for alternative solution : [[SSRS report definition is newer than Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902037/ssrs-report-definition-is-newer-than-server][1])

because i've got same eror on Visual Studio 2017 and only this solution works for me.