# Build tool to convert SSRS projects report RDL schema from 2016 to 2008 version

Tags: reporting-services, build, msbuild, ssrs-2008-r2, rdl

I have a number of SSRS reports that are currently in 2016 schema and need to be converted to 2008 R2 schema upon build.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Is it actually possible to do this? Does Microsoft provide a tool for this purpose?

It is difficult to find information on this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks all!

Comment: If you mean you want to deploy to a 2008R2 server, then I think you can just change the `Target Server Version` in the project settings in Visual Studio.

Comment: @AlanSchofield is correct; to expand this slightly, when you're building the project and have set the `Target Server Version` as required, the actual RDL build artefacts file(s) with the 2008R2/2012/2014 schema will be available in the project `bin` folder. This assumes that there are no 2016 specific features in the report or the build/deploy will fail.

Comment: Seems like about the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902037/ssrs-report-definition-is-newer-than-server/54711646#54711646

Answer (score 12):

You can convert 2016 rdls to 2008 r2 version by following below simple steps :

- Update Version 2016 to 2008 in first line.
- Delete two lines of both opening and closing part of the ReportSection and ReportSections.
- Delete complete ReportParametersLayout part.

Comment: As for the last step it was *ReportParametersLayout* in my case (notice plural for ParameterS), but it worked at the end, so thanks a lot!

Comment: Works sometimes. The other answer below works 100%..

Answer (score 5):

## Using Visual Studio 2017.

1. Right click on Project then Go to **Properties**.

[image: Project Properties]

2. Change **TargetServerVersion** to any of the following then click OK

   SQL Server 2008

   SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012 or 2014

[image: TargerServerVersion]

3. This step is *crucial*. when you are done with the design.

   - Right click *RDL* or *project* and click ***Build.***

[image: Build]

depending on build configuration you should have rdl file created for you in the follwing path.

```
\bin\Release\report1.rdl

\bin\Debug\report1.rdl
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.  This is much easier than messing around manually editing the RDL structure as some other answers suggest.

Comment: This is the best solution. Modifying the XML is terrible and doesn't always work.