# RDLC report stop working after change Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, rdlc

I have an AspNet MVC project in Visual Studio 2017 that was previously developed in Visual Studio 2015. This project contains many **rdlc files** that were working fine until I edited one of them. Now, when I try to download the pdf from the rdlc edited I get this error:

> The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this
>   version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been
>   created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content
>   that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services
>   schemas. Details: The report definition has an invalid target
>   namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition'
>   which cannot be upgraded.

The rdlc edited changes its namespace from http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition to http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition

The project is running with **net framework 4.6.2** and it has installed **Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.Common.12.0.2402.15** and **Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.WebForms.12.0.2402.15** nuget packages

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it uninstalling the nuget packages **Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.Common** and **Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.WebForms** and installing the package **Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.140.340.80**. I would like to highlight that I had to add a reference to **System.Windows.Forms** because there is a dependency in the class `ReportDataSource` that I use to render my reports

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms/                                       Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms -Version 140.802.134

Comment: Fidel Thank you for asking this question clear and thank you so much Lilliam for answer. It was 3 days i was looking for a solution for this.
For those who are looking solution for WPF application you need to install this package: **Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.140.340.80**

Comment: I'm having the same problem in a WebApi 2.0... 
The scenario is different, I'm not using Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.WebForms, I'm using only Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.Common...

Comment: This solution works, also do make sure the property "Build Action" of your RDLC-report is set to "Content", in my case was set to "Embedded Resource" and it was generating an error when I published to a production server. If your RDLC-report uses .resx files also verify they exist in their respective folder.

Comment: another thing should be considered , install nuget package for "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" version 14 , Of course our project is dotnet and our db is microsoft sql server

Comment: Cannot find version 140, only 150.  Still get following error trying to upgrade from SSRS 2005 to 2016:  "The base class includes the field 'ReportViewer', but its type (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer) is not compatible with the type of control (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)."

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this where this error occurs for users upgrading to Visual Studio 2019 here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/72790325/1165173

Answer (score -2):

I right clicked the rdlc file in the solution explorer and selected replace from server and it fixed the problem for me.  I think vs 2017 tries to update the schema to use a different version of sql server and getting the original report definition fixes it. Maybe, I don't know, but it worked for me.

Comment: It changed the schema back to this, <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"> from something like this <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"> for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what your answer is about. Could you explain more?

Comment: This answer neither identifies the problem or provides a permanent solution - clearly the person asking the question needs to be able to edit the RDLC file, not just pull it from the server.