# The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. (Error)

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewer

I've installed the extension Microsoft RDLC Report Designer in Visual Studio 2017 in order to modify my .rdlc files that were created with an older RDL scheme 2008.

The problem is that the designer is changing the scheme to version 2016 and when I try to run my report I'm getting the next error:

The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

As a first solution, I had to change manually the report adapting the changes to the old format(2008) but it's pretty annoying doing it all time.

Could you recommend me another kind of solution?

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked the target server version in the project properties?

Comment: @AlanSchofield I have a Class Library project for this report, I'm using Microsoft Report Viewer NuGet.  So it's an only client reporting service.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question properly, I didn't notice the RDLC reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty anoying. I've discovered another workaround, this way i dont need to update the xml to the old format everytime, give it a try:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61072633/9026516