# How can I change the TargetServerVersion to SQL Server 2008 in Visual Studio 2022? VS not showing solution properties "general" tab

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2022, rdlc, reportviewer

My Microsoft report viewer definition changes from 2008 to 2016, if parameter from toolbox added, as told in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927302/microsoft-report-viewer-defination-changes-2008-to-2016-if-parameter-from-toolb).

The problem is that Visual Studio doesn't show me the properties to change it, it even doesn't show me the "General" tab.

[This is the solution's properties page, It only shows "Configuration" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL4fn.png)

I tried The projects properties as well or looking configs by search or in the datasets, but nothing seems to appear.

Editing it by hand works, but I need to do it with any change I want to do. I'm looking if there is a way to configure my IDE to work as intended. :)

Comment: Pretty sure you can't. I'm not sure what was the oldest version to support 2008 (It has been completely unsupported for 4 years). It might be you need to use BIDS on VS 2008 (you certainly do for SSIS).