# SQL Server reporting services version issue

Tags: reporting-services

I am facing following error during deployment of SSRS report on server.

**The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services.**

I have been trying to find out issue on internet for two days but no luck.

Reporting Services version on Server:12.0.2000.8

On my local machine I have **SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU 2014**, **SQLEXPR_x64_ENU** and **VS2012 BIDS**. We have few other reports already running on server. When I create a new one and try to deploy on server I got the above error.

Please help.

Comment: You have developed a new report using VS2012 BIDS and you are deploying to an existing instance of SSRS 12.0.2000.8?

Answer (score 0):

The version of SSRS (Reporting Services) is 12.0.2000.8 which according to https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/ is SQL Server 2014.  If the version of SSRS is 2014 then it is **not possible** to deploy an SSRS report created using Visual Studio 2012 BIDS.

As an alternatively you can use Visual Studio 2017 which can deploy to SSRS 2008, 2008 R2 2012, 2014, and 2016 upwards.  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41436315/77198) for a screenshot of where you can make the changes.

This is the method I used to deploy SSRS reports to a 2012 and then a 2016 installation of SSRS.