# Report does not work in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting, rdlc

I have designed a report in vs 2015 and it looks like the following

[image]

And now I have installed vs 2017 installed in my machine and then while I want to open the rdlc file it opened as XML. and then I searched in google and I installed the missing Microsoft report viewer for 2017 and then it converted automatically and opened in design mode. Perfect.

But the problem is while I am going to run the project it gives me the following error.

[image]

Anyone, please help me.

Comment: This is not a debug issue first of all. Its an issue of version mismatch. Do you know how to update the reports related dll so that in runtime we will not get the error

Comment: ok, hope some body can come with a solution, if that is the case.

Comment: In VS2017, Tools -> Extensions and Updates, you should have an extension called "Microsoft Reporting Services Projects". Is that installed? Does it need updating?

Comment: no, not installed. I am installing it now and then let you know the update

Comment: i installed it but no luck. its the same error

Comment: You can read my answer at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590143/how-to-open-rdlc-in-design-mode/58256818#58256818