# Error with RDLC and NuGet Manager not working correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, nuget-package

I have recently went from VS 2013 to VS 2019 and have encountered issues with my rdlc's. I receive the following error when a run them

[image]

I was able to copy existing reports from one built in 2013 to 2019 and they seem to work however ones built within 2019 are not working.

I have tried to remove and then add the ReportViewer packages however I receive the following error

[image]

I don't know if I somehow broke NuGet or differences in creating a report between the two versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this exact problem in Visual Studio 2017, and managed to resolve it in VS 2019 as well.

Please read my answer here: [How to open RDLC in Design mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590143/how-to-open-rdlc-in-design-mode/58256818#58256818)

> For some reports, you might be needed to remove some XML tags from your rdlc report. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902037/ssrs-report-definition-is-newer-than-server) will guides you.

Hope find it helpful.. :)

Comment: Thank you that helped opening in design mode however it still gives me an error when I try running the report.

Comment: exactly as I expected. So you need to remove some tags in the XML schema of your report. you can open the rdlc in notepad to edit the XML so as to match with the correct schema. I edited the answer for you.

Comment: I followed the removal however I don't find MustUnderstand="df" or any reference to "df"

Comment: dear @Ether, no matter if you don't find it in the schema. just make sure it doesn't exist. some times it may bother you on other tags not mentioned in the post: like 'Page Break' tags. so remove them. you can add them later by the design view mode. In addition, creating new rdlc reports will be clean and work, not needing these steps.

Comment: Sorry in doing it over, I found that I forgot to remove the "ReportSection" opening and closing tags. It seems to be working. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, glad to hear that ... :)